# Why my button that links to a section within the same page not working within my jumbotron? It works outside of the jumbotron

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to have a button near the bottom of my jumbotron to link to a specific section within the page. However, the button won't even click. It won't even show anything when I hover over it. If I place the button outside of the jumbotron, it works fine. How can I get it to work within the jumbotron? The button is made with bootstrap, as well as the jumbotron. I have z-index on the overlay itself and the jumbotron. Not sure if that matters.

```
  <div class ="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id ="jumbo">
    <div class ="container" id ="jumbo-overlay">
      <h1 id ="jumbohead"></h1>
      <div id ="viewButt">
          <a class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary" href="#aboutme" id ="viewworkButt"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



#viewButt {

    padding-top: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;


}

#viewworkButt a:hover {

    background-color: yellowgreen;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `#viewworkButt a:hover` you are trying to select an `a` that is **inside** some element with id `viewworkButt`.

The correct CSS is:

```
a#viewworkButt:hover {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

So now it means: an `a` with `viewworkButt` as id.
Hope it helps.

Comment: You could add some text inside this `a`. Or you can set `display: block` and put some `width` and `height`, so it will have "real" dimensions.

Comment: Still nothing. Shouldn't it already have 'real' dimensions. Isn't it predefined from bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, it is. It was a guess. I don't get why it is not working. I just copied your code, added bootstrap and everything works fine. Could you show an example of live code? Like codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm so confused, the button doesn't appear as a button. My mouse cursor doesn't even change and it looks as if its a flat image.

Comment: The `a` is inside a `button` tag. You could do the opposite. Put the `button` inside the `a`. Then in CSS you could replace `a#viewworkButt:hover` to `a#viewworkButt button:hover`. I believe it can solve the issue.

Comment: It works both ways but the point is it won't work inside the jumbotron.